# Error When Insert data frame using RMySQL on R

Tags: r, rmysql

Using R, I tried to insert a data frame. My script looks like below:

```
con <-  dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), username = "xxxxxx", password = "xxxxxx",host = "127.0.0.1", dbname = "xxxxx")
dbWriteTable(conn=con,name='table',value=as.data.frame(df), append = TRUE, row.names = F)  
dbDisconnect(con)
```

WHen the script hit below line:

```
dbWriteTable(conn=con,name='table',value=as.data.frame(df), append = TRUE, row.names = F)
```

I got an error like below:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : could not run statement: Invalid utf8 character string: 'M'
```

I am not sure why this error occurred. This is a part of script that has been run well on another machine.

Please advise

Comment: I think the error is clear: there is an encodings issue, perhaps addressable with `iconv`. When you say that this has *"run well on another machine"*, please confirm that (1) `df` was perfectly identical on both; and (2) the two clients are connecting to the same database server. Additionally, it might be beneficial for us to see some representative data, though the culprit is not always present in every row of data. Have you tried writing just a few rows at a time to see in which row the problem character(s) lies?

Comment: (Other things I would check: are both clients using the same version of R and version of `RMysql`? OS? Do they report the same results from `Sys.getlocale()`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create proper connection, then only can insert data frame to your DB.
 for creating connection username & password,  host name & data base name should  correct. same code only but i removed some parameter

try this:

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='password', dbname='my_database', host='localhost')
```

i just insert Iris data in my_database

```
data(iris)  
dbWriteTable(mydb, name='db', value=iris)
```

i inserted iris data frame in the name of **db** in **my_database**